# download.default_directory selenium java not working in 84 chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to change the default chrome driver download path in selenium java.

```java
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         
prefs.put("download.default_directory", " path ");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Is there any console logs? Whether file downloading to the system download directory?also it will.be good if you give your `path` which you are using in the code

Comment: It is downloading in default downloads, and path given is "C:\\Desktop\\Test"

Comment: Please try with this C:\\Desktop\\Test\\

Comment: Chrome disallows using certain directories for download. In particular, you cannot use the desktop folder as the download directory. Reference: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Comment: C:\\Desktop\\Test\\ Didnt work. Where as as mentioned in https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities I am using java and C:\\ alone, any solution to resolve this ?

Comment: As per chromdriver documentation it will not work with your desktop path. Use your local disk path like D,E instead of C.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is great and meets the official manual.

I think the problem is with `path` parameter.

The following come from the chromedriver official manual:

> However, there are several caveats to be aware of:
>
> 1. Chrome disallows using certain directories for download. In particular, you cannot use the desktop folder as the download
>    directory. On Linux, you also cannot use the home directory for
>    download. Since the exact list of forbidden directories is subject to
>    change, it is recommended that you use a directory that has no special
>    meaning to the system.
> 2. ChromeDriver does not automatically wait for download to complete. If you call driver.quit() too soon, Chrome might terminate before the
>    download has finished.
> 3. Relative paths do not always work. For best result, use full path instead.
> 4. On Windows, Use "\" as path separators. Using "/" is not reliable on Windows.

**IF** the manual does not work for you, try this one that works but isn't smart:

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("chrome://settings/downloads");

// add some operation that change the default download directory
```

Comment: in my case. Still it doesn't work. My code is like below
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", new File(Conf.EXP).getAbsolutePath()); where Conf.EXP contains path of C:\Java\Git\. in previous versions it was working fine.